# Replacing information within XML tags

Tags: python, xml, svg, elementtree

I am trying to replace the information in an SVG file using ElementTree, however I am very new to it and haven't been making much progress.

So far, my code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('path-to-file')
root = tree.getroot()
for item in root.iter('tspan'):
    print(item)
```

However this doesn't find anything.
The SVG file information that I'm trying to locate is in the form:

```
<text
     transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,0,2286,3426)"
     style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:123.10199738px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:ArialMT;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
     id="text79724">
  <tspan
     x="0 71.891571 154.0006 188.22296 256.66766"
     y="0"
     sodipodi:role="line"
     id="tspan79722">&lt;SI1&gt;</tspan>
</text>
```

Where I am specifically looking to change the

```
x="0 71.891571 154.0006 188.22296 256.66766"
```

to `x="0"`.

I am not set on using ElementTree to do this, however, most similar StackOverflow questions suggest that it's the best idea.

Comment: Probably could've still used ElementTree instead of beautifulsoup (why use beautifulsoup when SVG is well-formed XML??), but SVGs are usually in a default namespace so you'd just have to adjust for that.

Comment: @DanielHaley would you be able to expand on that? I have no experience with ElementTree and BeautifulSoup is proving to affect the SVG undesirably

Comment: Sure. Do you have a more complete SVG example? (At a minimum, can you give me the "svg" start tag at least so I can see any xmlns?)

Comment: `for iten in` and then `print(item)` - of course it finds nothing Use a good IDE which will find such bugs for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in the question, you are not set to using ElementTree - so here is a solution using `beautifulsoup`:

```
data = '''<text
           transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,0,2286,3426)"
           style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:123.10199738px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:ArialMT;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="text79724"><tspan
             x="0 71.891571 154.0006 188.22296 256.66766"
             y="0"
             sodipodi:role="line"
             id="tspan79722">&lt;SI1&gt;</tspan></text>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tspan in soup.select('tspan[x]'):
    if tspan['x'] == '0 71.891571 154.0006 188.22296 256.66766':
        tspan['x'] = 0

print(soup.prettify())
#if writing to a new svg file, use soup instead of soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<text id="text79724" style="font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:123.10199738px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:ArialMT;writing-mode:lr-tb;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" transform="matrix(0,-1,-1,0,2286,3426)">
 <tspan id="tspan79722" sodipodi:role="line" x="0" y="0">
  &lt;SI1&gt;
 </tspan>
</text>
```

---

CSS selector `tspan[x]` will select `<tspan>` tag with attribute `x`. Then we check if attribute `x` is `'0 71.891571 154.0006 188.22296 256.66766'`. If it is, we set it to `0`.

Comment: Would I then need to write the output of this to a new file? I need to do this to ~150 SVG files

Comment: @JonathanDyke Yes, now it's changed in memory. You can then write the soup to file. Use a loop to change the ~150 files: each iteration load content of the file to soup, select tspan tags, change them and write the soup back to file.